# A problem about usb keyboard driver in linux-2.6.34

Tags: linux, operating-system, keyboard, driver, usb-drive

The usb keyboard driver of Linux is drivers\hid\usbhid\Usbkbd.c, but when I use printk to output a message in this program, when I press the keyboard, I don’t get the prompt message?

I want to know why. Thank you very much!

Comment: 2.6.34 is more than 13 years old. Wouldn't you rather experiment with a current version?

Comment: printk prints to the kernel log buffer. It will show the message on the console if the priority is high enough.